# AC can only go one direction

Tags: electrical, wiring, solar

I'm currently sending grid power from my house to a shed, and I'm now trying to send solar power from an inverter back to the house. I'm confused because the house can power the shed (120V AC displaying from an outlet in the shed, but when I connect an inverter to the shed outlet, I am reading negligible AC output at the house outlet (60V AC) after disconnecting the outlet from the grid. Why would it be that AC can go from the house to the shed and not vise versa? Is it possible there is some diode underground that blocks current from going the reverse direction?

I wish I could provide more details about the wiring, but I'm kind of working in the dark because it's underground and inaccessible. I've provided the crude drawing below based on my most likely flawed understanding.

EDIT

Sorry I remeasured the AC voltage from inverter to house and am reading 60VAC (not 6VAC) on the house end. Seems like only half of the sine wave is being sent for some reason.

I've included some pictures of my setup. The first one shows the outlet on the home, the power comes from the attic down the tube into the box, which feeds the outlet. The cord in picture 2 plugs into this outlet and powers the shed through underground wire with 120V AC. When it's not connected, the extension cord has no power. What's weird is the cord has 60VAC when connected to the inverter (nothing else) so something must be going on underground since the shed has 120VAC from the inverter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you intending to supply your house with solar power from the shed while the grid is down, or...?

Comment: Is it a grid-tie inverter? Or more generally, please provide make and model details of the inverter.

Comment: What synchs the AC frequency output of your inverter with the grid ?  I'm guessing nothing ?

Comment: The make of my inverter is a Reliable 1500 watt pure sine wave 24V Dc to 120V

Comment: The home outlet I connect to runs the pool pump circuit so whenever its sunny out I want to be able to use solar power. Otherwise, I'll probably use a double pole switch to use grid power in case there's not enough solar power.

Comment: @st4rgut -- so, you're OK with the solar power not working when the grid's down then?

Comment: it will still work, the solar system is completely off grid

Comment: @st4rgut -- that completely shoots past the intent of my question -- I'm asking if you have any reason you *want* solar power *while the grid is down* (i.e. during a blackout)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm OK with that. What are you proposing?

Comment: Holy smoke, I'm not touching this one with a 10 foot pole.  This whole deal is a sea of child-killing safety problems, shortcuts, code violations, huge skill gaps in the technology, extreme cheapness and shoddiness.  This is far, far beyond what can be handled in a single Q&A.  There are just too many "elephants in the room"...

Comment: @st4rgut your inverter is intended to run an appliance in a caravan or RV.    https://www.amazon.com/WZRELB-1500W-Solar-Inverter-Camping/dp/B07SPZWYY4

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Agree completely. It's one thing to understand electronics and electricity, it's quite another to install wiring safely and according to code.   To newbies I say:: "it might work, but not be safe, it might be safe but not up to code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you say the shed/house cable was completely disconnected from the input, and is being used the other way around, then there's something else going on.

1. You have not fully disconnected the link wire, and it is still connected to other wall jacks with load on them?
2. Your inverter is simply too small and the cable's length is causing too many losses.

But your underlying question is correct - wire does not care which way around it is installed so power doesn't have a preferred direction, or a "downhill".   AC power alternates direction every 50th/60th of a second, so power is going "both ways" many times a second.

What else do we not know ?

---

Your safest solution is something more like this:

[image]
Where powering something off the inverter means a physical disconnect and replug.  This will keep the off-phase AC separate

Off phase ?  The grid has a frequency of 60 or 50 HZ.  That's fixed and not going to change.  If your inverter pushes out the same frequency but off-set a little, then the two wave forms are going to cancel out, resulting in something like this (not to scale)

[image]

---

The other options are

1. a grid-disconnector installed at your main distribution board.  This is essentially a big master switch with two inputs (grid and inverter) and one output to the house.  To safely chance source it literally disconnects one and connects the other.  Everything in the house notices, though modern switchmode power supplies tend to be okay.   Better quality disconencts are softer, but some are like a mad-scientist throwing a big knife switch.
2. Use equipment that has dual power inputs.   Server computers often have two or more independent inputs for redundancy.   (I'm not sure what happens if a server is fed phase-shifted AC on another input... it should be okay but check that)
3. A local disconnector - originally for computer kit without dual PSU options, a local version of the disconnector can be installed to supply items.

---

There is no good and safe way to backfeed AC power to your house from the shed, using the existing cabling.  To do it right,  you need to install a reverse feed cable, and connect it to a mains disconnecter at the home's input.  Such an install would probably best involve a licensed and insured electrician, not bodging around.

---

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's possible to feed solar power to the house from the shed, but it'd either require living with the limits of a GT inverter, or using a multimode battery inverter or other energy storage system with microgrid capabilities at the house, AC coupling with the GT solar inverters at the shed

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel excellent point - Feeding DC from the panels/batteries back to the house, with the inverter in the house is another possibility.  Distance/losses could be an issue, and depends whether the inverter sits between batteries and solar panels.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to mess with grid power, and am planning to buy a SPDT switch to toggle between grid  when there's no sun and solar power. I've updated my question after measuring 60VAC from inverter. The overlapping sine waves is very intriguing, but I confirmed there is no other load at the outlet during measurement.

Comment: Thank you for the suggetions Criggie and ThreePhaseEel. My inverter is probably not adequate for the job. I do like the idea of sending dc to the house with the inverter in the house though and will try that out.

Comment: though on second thought the amount of current needed at 24V may be more than the underground wire can handle

Comment: @st4rgut Are you contemplating switching the one existing AC line to backfeed DC sometimes?  Because this sounds like a recipe for disaster.  I do see digging/trenching in your future, so whatever you bury make it in a generous conduit to allow for the future.

Comment: *> I'm not sure what happens if a server is fed phase-shifted AC on another input... it should be okay but check that* -- [it should be fine](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/155930-redundant-power-supply-on-different-phases), as the two are independently rectified to DC before reaching any other component.

Comment: It's OK to generate the AC near the panels.  Better for voltage drop actually. **But for power-outage support, there MUST be TWO separate cables between house and shed**.  One from house to shed for use at all times to power things in the shed... and the other for panel to house during outages. Your current wiring is *cordage* which is not proper at all, and with the plugs is outright dangerous. If you're into doing it all the right/safe way, let us know.

Answer (score 4):

### This is something the inverter's most likely doing, not your wiring

Grid-tie solar inverters are designed to feed power into an operating electric grid, and thus *need* a grid AC source to synchronize to.  If you deny them that grid source, they will refuse to invert.  This is to prevent the inverter from trying to power up a dead grid, which poses hazards to the linesfolk out in -20°C, 20m/s winds, and 20 cm of snow trying to get your power back on, as well as the health of the inverter.  Furthermore, grid-tie solar inverters don't have the ability to stably regulate grid frequency and voltage, or provide something called *reactive power* in order to keep the grid functioning properly, for that matter.

Note that if the shed is connected normally to the grid, and the grid is functional, a grid-tied solar inverter *will* supply power to everything: the shed, your house, and if anything is left over, up through the meter and service cable to the utility for somebody else to use.  It's doing this by synchronizing its own output to the grid-supplied AC waveform, though, hence the limitations described above.

### For what you want to do, you'll need a proper inverter, not some Cheese-pipeline special, though

The bad news is that for what you're after, your inverter is likely the wrong tool for the job.  Your average cheap inverter purchased on Amazon/eBay/AliExpress/... is meant for RV(caravan)/portable power usage, and thus isn't made or tested for grid-tied service, or for long-term off-grid use for that matter.  For what you're doing, though, you *need* an inverter that's been independently *tested* to meet the applicable national/power utility standards ("grid code") for interconnection to the electricity grid, even if you're running an off-grid system.  Given that you're outside North America, I would recommend a Victron MultiPlus multimode inverter.  These have good support for worldwide grid standards, extensive testing to *verify* that they comply with those standards, and are also going to be more rugged with regards to motor starting and such than your average cheap inverter will be.  Furthermore, they have models in the line that support 120V operation (vs. 230V), and can support off-grid operation either in addition to or instead of grid-tied service, as they have an internal switch in them that lets them *automatically* disconnect the inverter from the grid when mains power goes away while still providing inverter power to a set of standby loads wired to a second set of AC terminals on the inverter.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/WZRELB-1500W-Solar-Inverter-Camping/dp/B07SPZWYY4 seems to be OP's inverter.  It has no place in a hardwired building installation.